# how to write a loop in which a dataset is split and the slope of the trendline for each split is given in R

Tags: r, loops, linear-regression, bigdata

I've got an issue for which I couldn't find the solution after hours of research, so maybe one of you can help me out on this one:

my dataframe looks as follows:

```
stations_id phase_id refyear day  
140 10 1992 260  
140 10 1993 263   
140 10 1995 260  
140 10 1995 257   
140 12 1993 286  
140 12 1994 289  
140 12 1997 290  
150 10 1992 260  
150 10 1993 270  
150 10 1994 274  
165 15 1992 310
```

The dataframe has about 600,000 rows and therefore I am desperately trying to create a for-loop that puts out the slope of the regression line with "refyear" as independent variable and "day" as dependent variable for each combination of "stations_id" and "phase_id"; hence the splitting is dependent on two variables. 
However, I really can't find the solution and would really appreciate if somebody could help me out!

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr` and `broom`, you can model `refyear` vs. `day` by group without resorting to a loop and return a data frame with the model coefficients. In the code below, the regression coefficients are in the `estimate` column. The regression slopes are in the rows where `term` is equal to "day".

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

models = dat %>% group_by(stations_id, phase_id) %>% 
  do(tidy(lm(refyear ~ day, data=.)))
```

> ```
>   stations_id phase_id        term     estimate    std.error   statistic     p.value
>         <int>    <int>       <chr>        <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>
> 1         140       10 (Intercept) 2080.4166667  94.44595383  22.0275891 0.002054594
> 2         140       10         day   -0.3333333   0.36324158  -0.9176629 0.455668946
> 3         140       12 (Intercept) 1750.6923077 153.66666453  11.3927917 0.055736327
> 4         140       12         day    0.8461538   0.53293871   1.5877132 0.357824750
> 5         150       10 (Intercept) 1956.9230769   8.92887743 219.1678734 0.002904693
> 6         150       10         day    0.1346154   0.03330867   4.0414519 0.154420958
> 7         165       15 (Intercept) 1992.0000000          NaN         NaN         NaN
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tidyverse/purrr solution that I think is cleaner than a for-loop version.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(purrr)
d <- read_csv("stations_id, phase_id, refyear, day  
140, 10, 1992, 260  
140, 10, 1993, 263   
140, 10, 1995, 260  
140, 10, 1995, 257   
140, 12, 1993, 286  
140, 12, 1994, 289  
140, 12, 1997, 290  
150, 10, 1992, 260  
150, 10, 1993, 270  
150, 10, 1994, 274  
165, 15, 1992, 310")

nested <- d %>% 
  group_by(stations_id, phase_id) %>% 
  nest()  

nested <- nested %>% 
  mutate(mod = map(data, ~lm(day ~ refyear, data = .)))

map(nested$mod, coef)

[[1]]
 (Intercept)      refyear 
2032.2222222   -0.8888889 

[[2]]
  (Intercept)       refyear 
-1399.4615385     0.8461538 

[[3]]
(Intercept)     refyear 
     -13683           7 

[[4]]
(Intercept)     refyear 
        310          NA
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [tidyverse](http://www.tidyverse.org/) to achieve this.

First group by the variables, then [`tidyr::nest`](http://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/nest.html) the data by that grouping. Now you have a list-column that contains all the data from the non-grouping variables for each combination of the grouping variables.

Then you can use [`purrr::map`](http://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map.html) within [`dplyr::mutate`](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate.html) to iterate over the new list-column fitting your model on each separate daraframe within the list-col. Now you have an additional list-col containing the models. You can then iterate over these again, taking the desired coefficient from each model.

Finally you can either just select the slope and you'll have single row for each combination of the grouping vars with the slope from your models. Or you can `unnest` the data and have the slope added as a new column that repeats for all the values of the grouping vars.

For more detailed guide to these sorts of workflows check out the chapter on [many models](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html) from [R for Data Science](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/)

```r
library(tidyverse)

nested <- mtcars %>% 
  select(cyl, mpg, wt) %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  nest()

#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>     cyl              data
#>   <dbl>            <list>
#> 1     6  <tibble [7 x 2]>
#> 2     4 <tibble [11 x 2]>
#> 3     8 <tibble [14 x 2]>

models <- nested %>% 
  mutate(
    model = map(data, ~lm(mpg ~ wt, data = .x)),
    slope = map_dbl(model, c("coefficients", "wt"))
  )

#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>     cyl              data    model     slope
#>   <dbl>            <list>   <list>     <dbl>
#> 1     6  <tibble [7 x 2]> <S3: lm> -2.780106
#> 2     4 <tibble [11 x 2]> <S3: lm> -5.647025
#> 3     8 <tibble [14 x 2]> <S3: lm> -2.192438

models %>% select(cyl, slope)

#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>     cyl     slope
#>   <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1     6 -2.780106
#> 2     4 -5.647025
#> 3     8 -2.192438

models %>% select(-model) %>% unnest()

#> # A tibble: 32 x 4
#>      cyl     slope   mpg    wt
#>    <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1     6 -2.780106  21.0 2.620
#>  2     6 -2.780106  21.0 2.875
#>  3     6 -2.780106  21.4 3.215
#>  4     6 -2.780106  18.1 3.460
#>  5     6 -2.780106  19.2 3.440
#>  6     6 -2.780106  17.8 3.440
#>  7     6 -2.780106  19.7 2.770
#>  8     4 -5.647025  22.8 2.320
#>  9     4 -5.647025  24.4 3.190
#> 10     4 -5.647025  22.8 3.150
#> # ... with 22 more rows
```